# Search for username inside a UNC path in a text file

Tags: powershell, search

I got a log file where I want to extract the username on a line where it says ERROR 5.

Example:

```
2018/04/13 10:48:04 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File \\myserver\shares\johnsmith\My Documents\examplefile.txt
```

I want to find the string "johnsmith" and put it in a new text file. 
My idea was to search for ERROR 5 and then find the string in between the fourth and the fifth "\"-letter.

I've found this while googling:

```
(get-content C:\temp\testlog.txt)  | % { 
    if ($_ -match "ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Copying File \\myserver\shares\ (.*)") { 
        $name = $matches[1]
        echo $name
    }
}
```

But doesn't really work.

Can anyone give me any clues what functions to use?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file path is always as described, this should give you the names, files and error codes for any matching lines it finds in the log file:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\testlog.txt  |
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ($_ -match "^.*ERROR (?<ErrorCode>(\d+)) \(0x\d+\) Copying File \\\\myserver\\shares\\(?<UserName>\w+)\\My Documents\\(?<FileName>.*)$") 
        { 
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                UserName = $matches.UserName;
                FileName = $matches.FileName;
                ErrorCode = $matches.ErrorCode
        }
    }
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
UserName  FileName        ErrorCode
--------  --------        ---------
johnsmith examplefile.txt 5        
marysmith examplefile.txt 5        
adamsmith examplefile.txt 5        
philsmith examplefile.txt 5
```

To capture just the user names to file, modify the code to this:

```
Get-Content .\testlog.txt  |
    ForEach-Object { 
        if ($_ -match "^.*ERROR (?<ErrorCode>(\d+)) \(0x\d+\) Copying File \\\\myserver\\shares\\(?<UserName>\w+)\\.*$") 
        { 
            $matches.UserName
        }
    } | Out-File .\UserNames.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt really work as required. 
- I only need the username
- And the path "\My Documents\examplefile.txt" which comes after the username is just an example, it varies from every entry. I would like a wildcard after the username, because it doesnt have to be My Documents. The only relevant is the username and not the files themself. I tried to edit your script but it doesnt work 
"($_ -match ".*ERROR 5 \(0x00000005\) Copying File \\\\myserver\\shares\\(?<UserName>\w+)*$") "
- How do I make the output a txt file with one username per line?

Comment: @naikon, I added a simplified version that just saves the user names to file

Comment: Boxdog, you are an angel. It works excellent. I am very grateful for your help. I have one last question, right now it adds duplicate username depending on how many files there are with the error code. I really only need the name once. Is it possible to only add the username to the textfile once?

Comment: @naikon, yes. Replace the `Out-File .\UserNames.txt` with `Select-Object -Unique | Out-File .\UserNames.txt`